# linux how to tell the process for a script?

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I ran a script postData.sh, but when I do "ps -ef", I don't see the script in the list of programs running but I do see extra -bash processes running.  How do I determine the pid so I can kill the script as it is in the background right now?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: `-bash` in `ps -ef` shows a login shells. Maybe another shell is opened? Your scripts maybe exited because in `ps -ef` you always can see a path to script like this: `/bin/bash ./1.sh`

Answer (score 3):

To get the PID of a process use:

```
pidof postData.sh
```

Alternative Way:

```
pgrep postData.sh
```

Comment: nope, that's not working

Comment: than there is no process "postData.sh" running. to be sure you can check grep "postData.sh" /proc/*/cmdline - if this returns no match there definitly is no process running on your system that matches "postData.sh"

Comment: well, they all seem to be running as -bash when I do ps -ef and when they finish my -bash count goes from 16 to 6 (I have 10 running).  I see my startQa.sh in ps -ef but not these ones for some reason.....ahhh, I just realize the scripts I copied never had #!/bin/bash in them so that maybe screwed things up but I know they are running

Comment: resolved...that was it...missing the #!/bin/bash is very very bad...posted the answer for why I could not see my process below.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you find it as it'll print the process ID, parent process ID, and extended command

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,start_time,command
```

and this will make a handy tree of the processes.

```
pstree -pu
```

If you find something that you might wish to pause, to assess if its the right processes, you can `kill -STOP <pid>`, and resume with a `kill -CONT <pid>`

Comment: hmmm, the script was not listed at all though one of the commands the script is running was posted but there are 10 of these scripts running with different names and the commands are all exactly the same

Comment: @DeanHiller added to answer, maybe of use.

Comment: figured it out.  scripts were missing the #!/bin/bash so they don't show up in anything except as -bash.

Answer (score 2):

OKAY, I resolved it.  the scripts I copied off were missing the `#!/bin/bash` and for some reason when I run the script in ps -ef, it would just show up as -bash.  Now that I added the `#!/bin/bash`, it properly shows up as

```
[root@sdi-prod-01 manytables]# ps -ef | grep postTemp
root     29165 28764  1 10:51 pts/12   00:00:00 /bin/bash ./postTemp.sh 1
```

grrrrrr, that was annoying and all my scripts are already running but I can't tell them apart because of this....live and learn I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the last process you backgrounded you can simply `kill $!`.

Answer (score -2):

Using `ps -x` outputs the whole command.

Comment: Your answer could do with expanding a little.  It's unclear how the OP should use the `-x` or how this helps find the PID.

Comment: Calling a `ps -x`, grepping it with the name of the script, then filtering every word but the first (PID), f. i. with a `sed` call, then that can be stored in a bash variable, f. i. THEPID, and then just calling `kill $THEPID` should.

Comment: How is that an improvement over the `ps -ef` the OP said he's having trouble with?  Also, it's better to edit your answer when improving it rather than adding the good bits in the comments below the answer.

Comment: Maybe for being noob, but I resist editing already commented comments because of trying not to _steal sense_ from the _at some extent child_ comments. Reading again am starting to think that the shell the OP is trying to find is actually no longer.

Comment: It's your _answer_ that needs editing, not a comment.

Comment: Yay, am sorry, it is the answer what I meant to write, say, wanted to write _I resist editing already commented answers_. Oh noes, can not edit that old comment of my own. Better drink ma own piss. God save me now.

Comment: That's not how things work here. You are highly encouraged to edit and improve both questions and answers.